# Change Button Background in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a button inside a `UICollectionViewCell` (custom class) in a `UICollectionView`. When the button is clicked, it changes its background color. Works perfectly at first, but when I change the background color of the main view, I can't update the background color of the button. The background colors are stored in an array and here's the cell set-up function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("Rebuilding cells")
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ColorCollectionViewCell
    cell.button.tappedColor = backgroundColors[section]
    cell.button.originalColor = backgroundColors[section + 1]
    cell.button.delegate = self
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didHitButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

So if I start with `section` as 1, it loads the cell's button with the proper background color (black which is the first color in the section array. Then, I set the count to zero and `grid.reloadData()` which successfully wipes out the cells.

But then when I set `section` to 2 and reset the total cell count again, the cells don't adopt the new background color (section 2 color is green). They stay black from section 1.

How would I go about telling the `UICollectionView` to repaint the button background color in the cell when the data updates, where that background color comes from an array based on a variable for the `index`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the `.backgroundColor` property of the views to set the background color to display it.

Other than that, with each `tableView.reload()` all your tableView delegate methods are called again and your cells are re-binded with the data that you provide... so you have to treat them like they're un-initialized. This could also point out to, that if you're not getting the right colors assigned, black might be their default color and maybe its not working for `section` 1 as well or you should check the data stored in your array (you can debug or print them).

For a cleaner flow of logic just do:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    // do this for section 0
} else if indexPath.section == 1 {
    // do this for section 1
} else {
    // for all other if any
}
```

Hope this helps you in someway...

Comment: The button inside the cell is a custom class. tappedColor and originalColor set that background color for the button, so I'm doing that. It's just that reloading the data doesn't seem to update the values of tappedColor and originalColor to the next item in the color array and so those background color changes are not flowing through.

Comment: Well, debugging to find the cause is your best bet, put a breakpoint and check at the cellForRowAt method to see if your array contains the correct values and if the section values come correct as well... 

Also, have you tried the if-else method checking for section value like in my answer? since you're indexing your array with section and section+1, if you got two sections then you'd get 0,1 and 1,2...